# System is booting to "emergency/rescue mode"

Tags: linux, embedded, u-boot, yocto

This may not be the issue with Yocto itself but rather related to properly booting up Linux on Avenger96(STM32MP1) board. I am currently working on Avenger96 with Yocto(Dunfell). Aim is to implement SWUpdate OTA update system. For this I am using A/B strategy. Also I am using `systemd` instead of `sysVinit`. In my `conf/local.conf` I have set:

```
DISTRO_FEATURES_append = " systemd"
DISTRO_FEATURES_BACKFILL_CONSIDERED += "sysvinit"
VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_init_manager = "systemd"
VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_initscripts = "systemd-compat-units"
```

My `.wks` file looks like:

```
part fsbl1 --source rawcopy --sourceparams="file=u-boot-spl.stm32" --part-name "fsbl1" --ondisk mmcblk --align 1 --size 256k
part fsbl2 --source rawcopy --sourceparams="file=u-boot-spl.stm32" --part-name "fsbl2" --ondisk mmcblk --align 1 --size 256k
part ssbl --source rawcopy --sourceparams="file=u-boot.itb" --part-name "ssbl" --ondisk mmcblk --align 1 --size 2M
part / --source rootfs --ondisk mmcblk0 --fstype=ext4 --label root_A --part-name "rootfs_A" --align 4096 --use-uuid --active --size 3G
part / --source rootfs --ondisk mmcblk0 --fstype=ext4 --label root_B --part-name "rootfs_B" --align 4096 --use-uuid --size 3G

bootloader --ptable gpt
```

I am able to create the image and could copy it to SD card. But while booting I am getting below issue/errors:

```
[  OK  ] Started D-Bus System Message Bus.
         Starting Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status...
You are in rescue mode. After logging in, type "journalctl -xb" to view
system logs, "systemctl reboot" to reboot, "systemctl default" or "exit"
to boot into default mode.
Press Enter for maintenance
(or press Control-D to continue):
```

On pressing "Ctrl+D", I get :

```
Reloading system manager configuration
[ 1306.916497] systemd-fstab-generator[202]: Mount point fsbl1 is not a valid path, ignoring.
[ 1306.940236] systemd-fstab-generator[202]: Mount point fsbl2 is not a valid path, ignoring.
[ 1306.947455] systemd-fstab-generator[202]: Mount point ssbl is not a valid path, ignoring.
Starting default target
.
.
```

Then it asks for login and I could login as "root".
I don't understand why it's going to emergency or resume mode. On googling I found that it is usually related to /etc/fstab. Below is /etc/fstab/ content (copied from board):

```
# stock fstab - you probably want to override this with a machine specific one
/dev/root            /                    auto       defaults              1  1
proc                  /proc              proc       defaults              0  0
devpts              /dev/pts         devpts    mode=0620,ptmxmode=0666,gid=5      0  0
tmpfs                /run               tmpfs      mode=0755,nodev,nosuid,strictatime 0  0
tmpfs               /var/volatile    tmpfs      defaults              0  0
 
# uncomment this if your device has a SD/MMC/Transflash slot
#/dev/mmcblk0p1       /media/card          auto       defaults,sync,noauto  0  0
 
/dev/mmcblkp1   fsbl1   vfat    defaults            0            0
/dev/mmcblkp2   fsbl2   vfat    defaults            0            0
/dev/mmcblkp3   ssbl    vfat    defaults            0            0
```

Also one more doubt: what happens when we do software updates from emergency/rescue mode? In my case, I could install updates (using SWUpdate) but after reboot system is again booting from old partition. But I could manually switch to updated partition from `u-boot env` and verify that new image is installed. So I am assuming this behavior is again related to some issue with u-boot(probably, newly set environment is wiped on next startup). And also I can do other stuffs like accessing `fw_printenv/fw_setenv`, set `bootlimit` and change partition from u-boot env..

I found that a `boot.scr` is being used and I have set below in the script. And `rootfspart` in u-boot header file as `"rootfspart=4\0" \`

```
setenv bootargs "${bootargs} root=/dev/mmcblk0p${rootfspart} rdinit=/bin/kinit rw rootwait single"
```

Can anyone please let me know what could be the potential issue here? Any advice on which direction to look into would be helpful.

Your help will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

P.S: Please let me know if any info is missing. Also when I checked with `journalctl -xb` after logging in I could only find `Alternate GPT is invalid, using primary GPT.` and `GPT: Use GNU Parted to correct GPT errors.`. But may be I missed something here.